# How to enable global menu for a specific application?

Tags: unity, globalmenu

Most of the time I find the global menu annoying but sometimes it is usefull in some  programs that was maximized specifically the WEBAPPS in unity where there are no menus.
So, are there anyway to disable global menu in unity but let some applications to use it?

Anyways, my system is Ubuntu 13.10.

Answer (score 2):

Inspired from here:
[DISABLE THE APPMENU (GLOBAL MENU) IN UBUNTU](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/03/disable-appmenu-global-menu-in-ubuntu.html)
you can do this to disable global menu for all applications first:

```
sudo su
echo "export UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0" > /etc/X11/Xsession.d/81ubuntumenuproxy
```

Then restart your computer.

And then you can change the ".desktop" files of WebApps and add "UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=1" in the "Exec=..." line. Something like this:

```
Exec=UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=1 the_command_here
```

the "*.desktop" files are either here:

```
/home/USERNAME/.local/share/applications
```

where you replace USERNAME with your username
or here:

```
/usr/share/applications
```

Comment: Would editing the `.desktop` enable the global menu?

Comment: Yes I have tested it.